# UICollectionView Dynamic Cells Spacing and Order

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I've a CollectionView Cells like the one in the image, The Red Cells is the main cells and the green ones is sub-cells from the "0 cell" and the order isn't fixed.
My issue is that I can't set different space between cells as when I change the "minimumInteritemSpacing" value it will change the space for all cells
I was thinking of two options:
the **first** is to make empty cells to fill that spaces and the **second** is to use sections and make each row in different section
can anyone suggest a solution for me. here's what I reached so far:

My CollectionView:

```
 lazy var MyCV: UICollectionView = {
    
    let myLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    myLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    myLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 12
    myLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 12
    myLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 30, bottom: 0, right: 12)
    
    let MycollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame,collectionViewLayout: myLayout)
  MycollectionView.delegate = self
  MycollectionView.dataSource = self
    MycollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#FEFEFE")
    MycollectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    MycollectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
   MycollectionView.contentSize = .zero

   return MycollectionView
}()
```

collectionView CellForItem:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if indexPath.item == 0 || indexPath.item == 6 || indexPath.item == 7 || indexPath.item == 8{

          let cell = MyCV.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
            cell.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#F1F3F4")
            cell.titleLabel.text = itemsArea[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
        
        else{

       let Subcell = MyCV.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:"SubCell", for: indexPath) as! MySubCell
        Subcell.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#F1F3F4")
        Subcell.titleLabel.text = itemsArea[indexPath.row]
        return Subcell 

      }
}
```

Cell Size:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        return CGSize(width: 70, height: 30)
      }
```

[image]

Comment: for now I solved my problem with the sections option and it's quiet what I wanted, but I still wonder if there's a better solution